# HP BiosConfigUtility Set BIOS Password from Windows PE

Tags: windows, cmd, boot, portable-executable, bios

I try to configure the BIOS password from a batch script run in Windows PE, booted from USB stick. But after running the skript, I/m still able to enter the BIOS setup without a password. I already checked the HP instructions and Googled the issue but nothing works. This would be the part of script related to the issue:

```
START "" "X:\Windows\BIOSUtility\HpqPswd64.exe" /s /p"12345678" /f"C:\password.bin"
START "" "X:\Windows\BIOSUtility\BiosConfigUtility64.exe" /cspwdfile:"C:\password.bin"
```

Version of HP BCU is: 4.0.21.1
X: Is the drive of Windows PE from the USB Stick.
HP BCU works since earlier in the script I can pass the BIOS configuration with:
START "" "X:\Windows\BIOSUtility\BiosConfigUtility64.exe" /setConfig:BIOSConfigHPEliteDesk800G1.txt

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is there any error message? If so, please copy and paste it into the question. You should also start a query with HP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [User Guide for HPs BIOS Config Tool](http://whp-aus1.cold.extweb.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/whitepapers/BIOS_Configuration_Utility_User_Guide.pdf) the `/cspwdfile` switch
 is for providing the current password if one is already set and changes should be made. To set a new password you need `/nspwdfile` (or `/NewSetupPasswordFile` or `/npwdfile`)